# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException Unable to init from given binary data

Tags: laravel, image, api, postman

I need to make image from a blob data.I am using Laravel framework and Postman .But in some cases image is not creating and it shows an error Unable to init from given binary data.
My controller function have following code

```
if ($request->get('logo')) {
        $image = $request->get('logo');
        $pos  = strpos($image, ';');
        $type = explode(':', substr($request->get('logo'), 0, $pos))[1];
        $type = explode("/", $type);
        $name1 = $request->user_id."-".time().'.'.$type[1];
        $profile->logo = $name1;
        if (!File::exists(public_path().'uploads/profiles/logo')) {
            File::makeDirectory(public_path().'uploads/profiles/logo', $mode = 0755, true, true);
        }
        \Image::make($request->get('logo'))->save(public_path('uploads/profiles/logo/').$name1);
    }
```

$request->get('logo') contain value

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAQ4B4ADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAQUBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAgADBAUGBwgJAf/EAFwQAAEDAgMGAgYGBwQGBwYBDQIAAwQFEgYiMgcTFEJSYiNyCBUkM4KSFkNTorLCASU0RGNz0jFUYeIJERdkg5MYJjVBRXTwITZRVZSjJ4Sz8hlGVpHTN3GBw+P/xAAbAQADAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEBQEGB//EADoRAAICAQMDAwMCBAUDBAMBAAACAxIEEyIyAQVCERRSIzEzIWIVJEFDNFFhcXIGU5GBg…4V6aSSVCokkkkgCSSSQACkQ43Eu28nMkkvGPFNHGjXhaI5E1UntyO4a+JJJTNLcSpUiNDvzO6Ekl6wik6ywMqAwSSUywCGTJajDcRJJJRGKGZMdk9gKKkkmM4CSSSCQ09/Yo6SSVgO9ejlSrKNU5xD+0Pi0J+X/9NcfxzP8AWWMq3JIr7pRAPlHKkksac2OnP/hkKUEQAkkrHMHgBKy/KkkgBGFmVd49EKNfjqoO/wC6iH30klGf8RfH/Kp2raFMvxbLzaBEPuLyPtCn8Tj+sO3ZAfs+XIkkuBDzNWfxUVNZvdu5FuMKgNjubP0JJLl9yOTHxNQczcjkWCxVWHZLpscgkkkubiCSmfZTqSS7JIkciSSSiRDSSSQA6CaeeSSXi9AIhmkkktgDV5XJXpJJwAvSvSSQBHM86jvGkkqnig3oC0JJIKAJJJLQAlYU0yszaEklOTiBON6wkt8kkuf6dBAr0KSS9AA01MesaSSVlArzkkepMpJLaAkKSSAP/9k=
```

And on posting data from postman API I got the error

```
Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException
Unable to init from given binary data.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $image = $request->file('logo');
        $pos  = strpos($image, ';');
        $type = explode(':', substr($request->get('logo'), 0, $pos))[1];
        $type = explode("/", $type);
        $name1 = $request->user_id."-".time().'.'.$type[1];
        $profile->logo = $name1;
        if (!File::exists(public_path().'uploads/profiles/logo')) {
            File::makeDirectory(public_path().'uploads/profiles/logo', $mode = 0755, true, true);
        }
        \Image::make($request->get('logo'))->save(public_path('uploads/profiles/logo/').$name1);
    }
```

Comment: I am passing blob  data as $request->get('logo').Not image file